# Netty 4.0.19.Final Memory Leak with io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer$Entry

Tags: java, memory-leaks, netty

I seem to be experiencing recurring memory issues with Netty 4. My app queries Minecraft servers for information and updates a database with that information. Currently it creates 300 connection requests every 10 seconds and sends packets if those connections are successfully completed.

A previous iteration of my querying app used Netty 3.2.5 and it ran for months on end nonstop with no issues. With Netty 4 however, it only runs a few hours before exhausting all available resources. Here is a screenshot of the memory sampling over a JMX connection.

[image: Memory sampling results]

As we can see, `io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer$Entry` is using up a large amount of memory. Any idea how to go about troubleshooting this? I'm available to provide code if you guys need. Thanks!

**Stephen C: This is not a duplicate of "How to find a Java memory leak". This has to do with Netty specifically, and I'm not trying to find out how to discover a memory leak - I've already discovered one with Netty. I have re-posted my question so that I have a chance of getting an answer.**

Comment: Did you try 4.0.21.Final? It has quite a bit of fixes and improvements. Also, please share the heap dump. E-mail to 't at motd dot kr'.

Comment: Yeah please share the heap-dump. This way we can check in more details. Also a re-producer would help. Thanks!

Comment: I will try 4.0.21.Final and report back after a few hours of testing. I emailed the heap dump to Trustin. Norman, a direct link is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6188711/heapdump.hprof

Comment: I can provide source code for reproducing the issue, but this program by nature uses a large amount of bandwidth and it is not likely that it will run properly from a development machine with a home internet connection. I can also provide JMX connection details for you guys to use.

Comment: Netty 4.0.21.Final crashed after about an hour. Same cause, also there are significant CPU usage spikes that I sampled to be coming from `Bootstrap.connect`

Comment: I took a look into the heap dump, and found nothing special.  As you mentioned, there are many `ChannelOutboundBuffer` entry objects in the heap, but it is expected.  Usually, the number of `ChannelOutboundBuffer$Entry` instances will be about 32 * the number of peak active channels.  I think your problem will simply go away if you increase the max heap size of the JVM.

Comment: However, I agree that having 32 times many entry objects pooled could be way too much for some applications like yours.  I guess we need to adjust the initial capacity of the `ChannelOutboundBuffer`.

Comment: I have filed an issue so that you can keep track of this problem: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2693 Let's continue the discussion there.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably due to a wrong usage of *reference counted* object (a new principle introduced in Netty 4). Your channel doesn't correctly release an object.

You can use `-Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=paranoid` to activate an auto memory leak detection in Netty.

See the documentation here: http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html